# What happens when you integrate using $d(e^x)$ instead of $dx$?

Tags: integration

If $x_i=\frac{(b-a)i}{n}$ then we can write limit as a Riemann Sum like this:

$$\int_a^b{x e^xdx}=lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i e^{x_i}$$

But if we rewrite the limit in this way...

$$\int_a^b{x e^xdx}=\int_a^b{x\times \frac{d(e^x)}{dx}dx}=\int_a^b{x\times d(e^x)}$$

...then how can we write a similar Riemann-Sum as in the first case?

What I am basically trying to figure out, is what it means to integrate over $d(e^x)$ instead of over $dx$. I cannot visualize or intuit it. What is really happening here?

Comment: You have to change your limits of integration to $e^a$ and $e^b$. You can almost have $d$(anything). Think of it as a different way to measure length where locations are weighted according to some function.

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the title, when you integrate "df" the result is "f+ a constant".  When you integrate "dx", $\int dx= x+ C$ and when you integrate "$d(e^x)$", $\int d(e^x)= e^x+ C$.

Comment: Ok, but what if we integrate $x \times d(e^x)$?

Comment: You integrate by parts

Comment: Since the derivative of $e^x$ is just $e^x$ itself, $d(e^x)= e^x dx$ and $\int x d(e^x)= \int x e^x dx$.  As samjoe said, use integration by parts, letting $u= x$ and $dv= e^x dx$ so that $du= dx$ and $v= e^x$.  Then $\int x d(e^x)= \int xe^x dx= xe^x- \int e^x dx= xe^x- e^x+ C= (x- 1)e^x+ C.